# Looking for a good shape class design for the use of elementary physics and rendering in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, physics, shapes

At the moment, I've been studying some OpenGL and I hope to learn as much as possible. Right now I'm writing out a shape class which I can hopefully use and derive from in other projects I choose to undertake. I've come to a realization however that there are certain elements which I need to take into consideration. One of these is the collection of mass, volume, and density - more so in relation as how to how they would apply to the geometric primitive itself.

Any axially aligned spheres or bounding boxes will likely be derived from this class, *as well as* primitives which will actually be rendered to the screen - both 2D and 3D alike. I was hoping to see if someone could give me some pointers on how to write a good Shape class without necessary "giving away the answer". I need a direction of some sort.

The two main resources I have at my side are Nicol Bolas' (I think that's how his name is spelled) [Learning Modern Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html), and the [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556229119) book. As far as fundamentals and advanced concepts in terms of rendering and the like, these should be sufficient.

What I'm looking for at the moment though is somewhat of a *guide* in terms of how I could build this class. The last thing I want to do for now is just follow tutorials which involve drawing triangles on the screen from static values because I'm just one of those people who doesn't learn too well that way; I learn as a I go by implementing my own methods and relying on other sources of information at the same time.

So far, this is what I have (**NOTE** - none of these methods have been implemented yet, apart from ctor and inlines):

```
class Shape
    {
    public:
        Shape(float radius, glm::vec4 center_pos);
        virtual ~Shape(void) { }

        virtual void draw(void) = 0;
        void collide(Shape& s);
    public:
        inline void setRadius(float radius)
        {
            mRadius = radius;
            redetermineStructure();
        }

    public:
        glm::vec4 CenterPosition;
    protected:
        float mass(void);
        void redetermineStructure(void); //used to recalculate the dimensions and attributes of the primitive after a new value such as radius or position has been set.
    protected:
        float mRadius, mVolume, mDensity;
        glm::vec4 mLastPosition;
        int mHP;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you already know what you're going to need (upfront design / prototyping) it's going to be difficult to give a specific answer.

If you learn by doing then I would suggest a good way to proceed would be to write some simple implementations which would make use of your shape class:

- 1D collision between two particles
- 1D collision between a particles and a plane
- Pendulums
- 2D collisions between 1 shape and 1 plane (boundary checking)
- 2D collisions between 2 shapes / multiple shapes (boundary checking, momentum transfer)
- 3D collisions with the above

...that should fairly quickly expose the sorts of member functions and internal storage your shape class is going to require.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do too much in one class. Modularity is very helpful in dealing with complicated systems. For example all the physics engines I have used ([bullet](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/), [ode](http://www.ode.org/), and [box2d](http://box2d.org/)) have separate objects for physical bodies and for collision geometry.

The body object contains its position, orientation, velocity and mass information. Mass is also often a separate object to manage the mass together with the moment of inertia. Then the body is used for determining acceleration from the forces in the system and integrating the system forward in time. The geometry object then contains the shape of the object either as a mesh or some other description. It is used for determining contact points.

If you are going to be drawing these objects I would use a separate module to do that as well. You could put all the drawing information and code in the shape object, but the physics side of things does not need to know about an objects texture or lighting information. Also you may want to draw an object differently than its physical representation and this will make it easier to do that.

Some other examples of why you would want this modularity are

- Static object that can collide with other physical objects but is not affected by them then you could use a shape object with no corresponding body object
- If you want to change the shape of something it is much easier to just switch out it's geometry member than to try and copy its information to another object.
- You will likely end  up wanting to draw things that are not physical at all so having a separate module for drawing will be helpful there
- If you decide at some point you want to switch your rendering system or use a 3rd party physics engine then if all your code is coupled in one class it will be much more difficult than if things are as modular as possible.